# PDO - Call to a member function (On a lot of connections)

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am experiencing this error on my website:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/public_html/page.php on line 27

This is my function:

```
function getSetting()
        {
            global $dbh;
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT setting_name, setting_value FROM settings");
            try
            {
                $stmt->execute();
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }

            $sdata = array();
            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $sdata[$row['setting_name']] = $row['setting_value'];
            }

            return $sdata;
        }
```

The above error is only happening when my website gets a lot of requests. I use the function like this:

```
//Get settings from database.
$site = new Site; //Load the Site class, where the function getSetting() is located
$sdata=$site->getSetting();
```

I suspect the problem being with my query, but I just can't figure out how to optimize it further.

Any help is greatly appreciated

**UPDATE:**

This is how I connect to the database:

```
try {
    $dsn = "mysql:host=" . $database['host'] . ";dbname=" . $database['db'];
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $database['user'], $database['pass'], array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT));     
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT); // <== add this line
    //echo 'Connected to Database<br/>';    
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

My `max_connections` is currently set to `250`

Comment: Clearly you're not checking that `$dbh` has been set correctly.... my gess would be that you've hit a maximum db connection limit, so the database connection is failing

Comment: @MarkBaker Valid point. I have updated my question, to include on how I connect to my database using $dbh

Comment: Are you sure there is data being returned? This could be the cause of a table that does not exist.

Comment: @RepeaterCreeper yes. Data is being returned. The problem only happens on some page loads.

Comment: turn off silent errors in PDO. Suppressing errors is **NEVER** a good idea, especially when you KNOW you've got problems.

Comment: Even if the PDO connection fails and throws an exception, you're still continuing script execution (after echoing the exception message), so (unless you're testing the value of $dbh elsewhere), you'll still try to execute a query against a database connection that has failed

Comment: @MarkBaker so how can I prevent that?

Comment: By doing something in your catch block to terminate further execution of the script

Comment: @MarkBaker But This error is happening on every other page load. Stopping the script will still result in the page die() ?

Comment: So you'd rather have `Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/public_html/page.php on line 27` being displayed to your users rather than an error message that you control?

Comment: @MarkBaker of course not. It's just, I would like the script not stopping on every other page load.

Comment: And knowing what is being displayed as the result of your catch block would help identify/confirm the real problem, and allow you to take steps to prevent it properly

Comment: If it's stopping on every other page load anyway, at least do it in a way that lets you present a user-friendly message rather than a PHP fatal error message

Comment: @oliverbj Do you mind trying this on an API called medoo and see if it works there? Because if you were to use the API that will eliminate possible SQL Query error and many other possible errors. However if that doesn't work and still returns an error I'm out of ideas.